# Geometrical representation of speed?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, geometric-interpretation

I've been learning about position vectors, and how their derivatives show the velocity (first derivative), and acceleration (second derivative) of a moving body.

From Mechanics I learned that, the area beneath the curve of the velocity vs time graph gives the displacement.

Now in Calculus I'm learning that, if you take the magnitude of the velocity vector you get the speed of the object. What I would like to know is how is this concept still true in more complex scenarios, where the acceleration of an object is not constant. For instance, take a look at the following [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgBIb.jpg). It is clear to me, that the area under the velocity curve is still equal to the displacement. But, how can you represent the speed of this object?

Comment: Speed = Area under the Acceleration Curve

Comment: @ja72 If you take the integral of acceleration with respect to time you get velocity. Speed would be the distance/magnitude of your velocity vector.

Comment: The graph you asked about shows $V(t)$ (presumably velocity) as a one-dimensional function of time $t$. That's the only way to make sense of the graph, which has a single axis for $V(t)$ and an axis for $t$. In that case, the _speed_ at any instant is just the absolute value of $V(t)$, or in other words the distance to the $t$-axis from a point on the curve. If you want velocity to be a multi-dimensional vector, you cannot use that graph as an example (unless $V(t)$ actuallly is _speed_ rather than _velocity,_ but in that case we're back to distance from the $t$ axis again).

Comment: The graph you plotted is not a velocity- time graph (even if it states ) it is the speed-time graph, since the graph does not have any type of information regarding direction. To clarify, think of any arbitrary point, it gives you the instantaneous speed at a given point.Eg. (3,6) states 3 seconds later the speed is 6 or the magnitude of the velocity is 6.

Comment: @Socre Would you mind elaborating a bit more on that idea? Or maybe showing an example of an actual velocity vs time graph, that would clear things up.

Comment: I cannot recall any "graph" I have ever seen of a multi-dimensional velocity (speed and non-trivial direction) vs. time in the sense that your graph plotted $V(t)$ (whatever that means in that graph) vs. $t$. Taking one or more "snapshots" of a velocity at particular times is much more common. If the "snapshot" represents the velocity as an arrow (which it quite often does), the speed is the length of the arrow. Otherwise it depends on how the velocity is represented.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you! It's much clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Velocity is a vector quantity. Imagine that a vector can be represented as an arrow. The arrow, then, has a direction and magnitude. Speed is the length of velocity's arrow, or in other words, speed is the magnitude of velocity. Formally, we can write this as

$$\text{velocity} = \vec{v}(t)$$
$$\text{speed} = |\vec{v}(t)|$$

In cases of nonconstant acceleration, the above still holds. The instantaneous velocity is $\vec{v}(t) = \frac{d\vec{r}(t)}{dt}$. You have likely seen one-dimensional examples, and in those cases we can say our object travels in the x-direction: $\hat{r}=\hat{x}$. In this case it is common to drop the vector notation and just write: $v_x(t) = \frac{dx}{dt}$

One way to visualize vectors is with a [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field) plot. Say we wish to describe the velocity of the wind in some region. First we set up coordinate axes. Then at each point we place an arrow: the orientation indicates the wind's direction and the length represents the wind speed. In the picture below, we have such a vector field of wind velocity as a function of position at some given time. The picture depicts Hurricane Katrina.

[image: vector field for wind. source: http://people.eecs.ku.edu/~miller/WorldWind/]

[image source](http://people.eecs.ku.edu/~miller/WorldWindProjects/VectorFieldVis/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Completely misunderstood the question. New answer:

Speed is the magnitude of velocity. Velocity is the derivative of displacement with respect to time. Therefore, the speed of a body at time $t$ is the absolute value of the slope of the line tangent to that body's displacement vs. time graph at time $t$.

You can get the displacement of the body as a function of time by graphing the area under the velocity curve (like the one you linked to) as a function of time.

Comment: That's the algebraic representation though. How would you represent that geometrically?

Comment: It's the absolute value of the slope of the tangent line of the displacement graph. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

> velocity= number+ direction.

So, the number simply states $\frac{ds}{dt}$, and the graph drawn is all numbers. To clarify ask yourself at **time=3**, what is the direction of this velocity? If you can answer it, then it is a velocity-time graph.
 Now have you ever heard of vector fields. This shows the direction and the magnitude scaled. This types of graphs actually shows the magnitude and direction of a velocity or any vector. And this Is used when we are concerned basically with the direction. @zahbaz has shown a type of vector field. [image]
Here is a simpler type of vector field at fewer points.
So the big question is **DO I GET MY DIRECTIONS OR IS IT PURE NUMBER**from the graph. If your graph had a notation that the plot is taken from a single direction (1D) then positive indicates forward and negative might indicate backward which turns to a velocity-time graph.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped clear things up.